# Is it possible in Java to create an Annotation for an interface, forcing implementing classes a specific parameter list for the constructor

Tags: java, interface, constructor, annotations

I'm in search of a way in Java to force classes that implement a certain interface to define a certain constructor.

Example:

```
@Constructor(X, Y, Z)
public interface A {}

public class B implements A {
    public B(X x, Y y, Z z) {}
}
```

In this case it would force the implementing class to contain a constructor with that parameter list. Is there any way to actually do this?

P.S. I understand this goes against the design practice of interfaces, it's just something that in my case the implementing classes need because of a certain compiler-decoupled factory method implementation.

Comment: Why not use an abstract class for that?

Comment: This isn't even possible with abstract base classes.

Comment: @Thilo well, in away it is. Either the implementing class has to define the same constructor parameter, or call super with the same constructor argument.

Comment: no, it just has to call an existing super constructor. The subclasses own constructor can have complete different (or no) parameters.

Comment: Yes, so in a way, the extending class knows of a contract it has to either define on its own or call the existing?

Comment: It's not about calling a certain constructor, it's about constructor definition meeting requirements that I would like to see possible to be structurally declared in the code.

Comment: Let me elaborate just a bit more: Let's say I would want to use the java reflection API to call the constructor of a list of classes of which i know they are of a certain interface. I would then love to be sure that I can always find a certain constructor in each of these objects, so to be able to define these requirements in the interface would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Ok roll out a maven plugin with classpath scanning for the implementing classes, and fail fast if the implementing class is not abstract and does not define the constructor requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an abstract class for that? Otherwise, you will have to roll out annotation processor and classpath scanning to check that all implementing classes obeys the annotation. If you decide to go this path, a maven plugin can also help during the compile phase and scan the classpath to ensure that the implementing classes have defined the constructor

Comment: You can't force a child class to have a specific constructor, only methods.

Comment: After quite a bit of research I've found that your method comes closest to my desired situation.